# internet and login spontaneously crash

Tags: 16.04, login, internet

I use 16.04 LTS, and about 2 hours or so after startup, it seems the Internet and the ability to login both crash.

As for the Internet:

I can reach localhost, but pinging the outside world yields "network is unreachable". `Settings -> Network` crashes the Settings window.  Trying to `Disconnect` from the network times out.

As for login:

It simply freezes, whether on the login screen (looping circle) or from a terminal (so cannot `sudo`).  I did `Ctrl-Alt-F1` and tried logging in from there.  It gave me the login welcome, ending in `4 packages can be upgraded, 0 of which are security packages` (or something like that), but would not give me a prompt.

It seems spontaneous, except like I said it seems to happen about 2 hours after startup.  Also, I think using `dpkg` might trigger it somehow, as a couple package installations have frozen (as has `--configure -a` when trying to recover), but I'm pretty sure it's not the only cause.

Any ideas on how to fix?  Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: OK additional info: I had Youtube on autoplay, going from song to song, for about an hour and a half.  Meanwhile, on tty2, I was pinging an outside site every 5 minutes.  Everything seemed to be going well, so I decided to take the plunge and lock the screen and log back in.  Alas, it froze.  I went to tty2 and noticed one more successful ping, and then it started saying network unreachable.

Comment: Somehow or another, I managed to use tty2 to "break-in" to tty7, removing the lock screen but also the launcher, the dash, and all window title bars, and so couldn't move any of the windows, but I could still use my web browser.  In the browser, new tabs could not connect to the Internet, _but the Youtube play-a-thon continued, and even played ads_.  I'm pretty sure, then, that the Youtube tab was still connected to the Internet, but otherwise my network access and ability to login was lost as before.  Perhaps this info will be useful?

Comment: Travis, you want to edit your question to make updates, don't do that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

APPARENT SOLUTION: I booted in recovery mode, went into the root shell, and did `dpkg --configure -a` from there.  Everything (including locking and unlocking the screen) seems to be working like a charm now.

It doesn't seem like this was the most popular question to answer, but thankfully I managed to get it working, and post this in the event my problem happens to anyone else.

Happy Ubuntuing :-)